# How to fixedly assure neo4j will return a Long value for attribute

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

i did some experiments with neo4j 2.3 version and direct calls on transactional endpoint

http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit

and create the node with long attribute

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"statements" : [ {
"statement" : "MERGE (c:`foo` {id:{_queryId}}) ON CREATE SET  c.`created`={created} RETURN c",
"parameters" : {
  "created" : 1111111111111111111
}}]
}'
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit"
```

While reading this data on client side (Java, Jersey  , REST client)
i receive the long or int depending the value
It looks like neo4j is compacting the data while returning result 
I proof it with pure postman call - so this is clearly neo4j server side issue - as follows

```
{
 "statements" : [ {
 "statement" : "MATCH c RETURN TYPE(c.created)"
 } ]
}
```

And i got either

> ```
>   "code": "Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure",
>   "message": "java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship",
>   "stackTrace": "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship\
> ```

or

> ```
>   "code": "Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure",
>   "message": "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship",
>   "stackTrace": "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship
> ```

Is there a way that as a consumer i could always get long ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That's actually due to the REST client. To be consistent, it's best to expect a `java.lang.Number` and then do a `longValue()` on it.

However, the exceptions you show in your post are because you're trying to use the `TYPE` function on a number. [TYPE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-type) expects a relationship and it returns the relationship type.