# Spring Data Neo4j (4.2.0M1) count Cypher query return type different from embedded DB than for remote one

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, embedded-database

We have found an issue by testing our code where a count cypher query is used. If the test is running against an embedded database (EmbeddedDriver) the returned value within the Result type is a Long (or an Integer, I dont' remember) and when the same test is running against a remote database (HttpDriver) the returned value within the Result type is an Integer (or a long ;).

This means that we can not implemet our code thinking it will return an Integer in our unit test cases and have a ClassCastException when the code is used in "production mode" against a remote database.

The current workaround is using the instanceof to correctly cast the returned value, but it is realy not performant and pretty...

Here is an example of one of these queries:

```
Object result = neo4jSession.query("MATCH (n) RETURN count(n) as result",
                    ...).iterator().next().get("result");

Long value = result instanceof Long ? (Long) result : new Long((Integer) result);
```

Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

The question crops up once in a while in various forms (see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772116/how-to-fixedly-assure-neo4j-will-return-a-long-value-for-attribute) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999835/cypher-creates-number-as-a-long-how-do-i-create-an-integer) for example).

It's best not to assume a type more specific than `Number`, then you can just do:

```
long value = ((Number) result).longValue();
```

No `instanceof`, no object creation.

Comment: I do agree with the workaround but the fact is more to know whether its a bug that the two types of Db are not returning the same java type...

Comment: Whether it is a long or int depends on the value especially over the neo rest api where the type isn't obvious. The ogm does not make an attempt to always convert numbers to a specific datatype as it does not understand what those numbers in custom queries represent. Treating it as Number as described by Frank is the recommended way